# A stone game - 2 players play perfectly

Tags: algorithm, game-theory

Recently I have learned about the nim game and grundy number
I am stuck on a problem. Please give me some ideas

**Problem:**
A and B play a game with a pile of stone. A starts the game and they alternate moves. In each move, a player has to remove at least one and no more than sqrt of number stones from the pile. So, for example if a pile contains 10 stones, then a player can take 1,2,3 stones from the pile.
Both A and B play perfectly. The player who cannot make a valid move loses. Now you are given the number of stone, you have to find the player who will win if both play optimally.
Example

n=3 A win,

n=5 B win

**n<=10^12**

I can solve this problem with small number of stone by using Grundy number https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/algorithm-games/?

grundy function is g(x) with x is the remain stones.
call F(s) is set of number of remain stone that we can obtain from x stone.
if s is a terminal position, g(s)=0

if s is not a terminal position, Let X = {g(t)| t in F(s)}. Then, grundy number of s is the smallest integer greater than or equal to 0 which is not in X.

for example x=10 so F(x)={9,8,7} by take 1,2 or 3 stones. (sqrt(10)<=3)

if g(n)>0 => the first player win

g(0)=0

g(1)=1

g(2)=0

g(3)=1

g(4)=2
....

but this algorithm is to slow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does B win 5? A takes 2, B has to take 1 or 2, A takes the last 1 or 2. Or did I misunderstand the rules? I guess I did, because I don't understand how someone can be unable to make a valid move.

Comment: If I understand the rules correctly, you lose if your opponent takes the last stone since you are unable to take at least one stone.

Comment: N=5, if A takes 2, remain 3 stones, so B only can take 1 stone (sqrt(3)=1.73..) => remain 2 stone, A also can take only 1 stones (sqrt(2)=1.41..) => remain 1 stone, B take it. B win.

"someone can be unable to make a valid move" means who take all remain stones win.

Comment: Oh, I get it; I thought the sqrt(5) rule remained in place throughout the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm adding a second answer because my first answer provides the background theory without the optimization. But since OP clearly is looking for some optimization and for a very fast solution without a lot of recursion, I took my own advice:

> Of course, the really fast way to do this is to do some more math and figure out some simple properties of n you can check that will determine whether or not it is a winner or a loser.

I'm going to use the terminology I defined there, so if this isn't making sense, read that answer! Specifically, *n* is the pile size, *k* is the number of stones to remove, *n* is a winner if there is a winning strategy for player A starting with a pile of size *n* and it is a loser otherwise. Let's start with the following key insight:

> Most numbers are winners.

Why is this true? It isn't obvious for small numbers: 0 is a loser, 1 is a winner, 2 is a loser, 3 is a winner, so is 4, but 5 is a loser again. But for larger numbers, it becomes more obvious.

If some integer *p* is large and is a loser then *p+1, p+2, ... p+k_m* are all winners for some *k_m* that is around the size of sqrt(p). This is because once I find a loser, for any pile that isn't too much larger than that, I can remove a few stones to leave my opponent with that loser. The key is just determining what the largest valid value of *k* is, since *k* is defined in terms of the starting pile size *n* rather than the final pile size *p*.

So the question becomes, given some integer *p*, for which values of *k* is it true that *k <= sqrt(n)* where *n = p+k*. In other words, given *p*, what starting pile sizes *n* allow me to remove *k* and leave my opponent with *p*. Well, since *n = p+k* and the values are all nonnegative, we must have

*k <= sqrt(n) = sqrt(p+k) ==> k^2 <= p + k ==> k^2 - k - p <= 0.*

This is a quadratic equation in *k* for any fixed value of *p*. The endpoints of the solution set can be found using the quadratic formula:

*k = (1 +- sqrt(1 + 4p))/2*

So, the inequality is satisfied for values of *k* between (1-sqrt(1+4p))/2 and (1+sqrt(1+4p))/2. Of course, sqrt(1+4p) is at least sqrt(5) > 2, so the left endpoint is negative. So then *k_m = floor((1+sqrt(1+4p))/2)*.

More importantly, I claim that the next loser after *p* is the number *L = p + k_m + 1*. Let's try to prove this:

> **Theorem:** If *p* is a loser, then *L = p + k_m + 1* is also a loser and every integer *p < n < L* is a winner.

**Proof:** We have already shown that every integer *n* in the interval *[p+1, p+k_m]* is a winner, so we only need to prove that *L* is a loser.

Suppose, to the contrary, that *L* is a winner. Then there exists some *1 <= k <= sqrt(L)* such that *L - k* is a loser (by definition). Since we have proven that the integers *p+1, ..., p+k_m* are winners, we must have that *L - k <= p* since no number smaller than *L* and larger than *p* can be a loser. But this means that *L <= p + k* and so *k* satisfies the equation *k <= sqrt(L) <= sqrt(p + k)*. We have already shown that solutions to the equation *k <= sqrt(p + k)* are no larger than *(1+sqrt(1+4p))/2*, so any integer solution must satisfy *k <= k_m*. But then *L - k = p + k_m + 1 - k >= p + k_m + 1 - k_m = p + 1*. This is a contradiction since *p < L - k < L* and we have already proved that there are no losers larger than *p* and smaller than *L*.

**QED**

The above theorem gives us a nice approach since we now know that winners fall into intervals of integers separated by a single loser and we know how to calculate the interval between two losers. In particular, if *p* is a loser, then *p + k_m + 1* is a loser where

*k_m = floor((1+sqrt(1+4p))/2)*.

Now we can rewrite the function in a purely iterative manner that should be fast and requires constant space. The approach is simply to compute the sequence of losers until we either find *n* (in which case it is a loser) or determine that *n* lies in the interval between two losers.

```
bool is_winner(int n) {
  int p = 0;
  // loop through losers until we find one at least as large as n
  while (p < n) {
    int km = floor((1+sqrt(1+4p))/2);
    p = p + km + 1;
  }

  /* if we skipped n while computing losers, 
   * it is a winner that lies in the interval 
   * between two losers. So n is a winner as 
   * long as it isn't equal to p.*/
  return (p != n);  
}
```

Comment: Looks like someone beat me to it :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to think this game recursively from the end: Clearly, to win, you have to take the last stone.

- 1 stone: First player wins. It's A's turn to take the only stone.
- 2 stones: Second player wins. A cannot take two stones but has to take one. So A is forced to take one stone and leave the other one for B to take.
- 3 stones: First player wins. There is still no choice. A has to take one stone, and smiles because they know that B can't win with two stones.
- 4 stones: First player wins. Now A has the choice to leave two or three stones. From the above, A knows that B will win if given three stones, but B will lose if given two stones, so A takes two stones.
- 5 stones: Second player wins. Even though A has the choice to leave three or four stones, B will win if given either amount.

As you can see, you can easily calculate who will win a game with `n` stones by complete knowledge of the outcomes of the games with `1` to `n-1` stones.

An algorithmic solution will thus create a boolean array `wins`, where `wins[i]` is true if the player given `i` stones will win the game. `wins[0]` is initialized to `false`. The rest of the array is then filled iteratively from the start by scanning the reachable portion of the array for a false entry. If a false entry is found, the current entry is set to true, because A can leave the board in a loosing state for B, otherwise it is set to false.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the number of stone is up to 10^12. Your algorithm would take a long time to run.

Answer (score 2):

I will build upon cmaster's answer because it is already pretty close. The question is how to efficiently calculate the values.

The answer is: We don't need the whole array. Only the `false` values are interesting. Let's analyze:

If we have a `false` value in the array, then the next few entries will be `true` because they can remove stones, such that the other player lands on the `false` value. The question is: How many `true` entries will be there?

If we are at the `false` entry `z`, then the entry `x` will be a `true` entry if `x - sqrt(x) <= z`. We can solve this for `x` and get:

```
x <= 1/2 * (1 + 2 * z + sqrt(1 + 4 * z))
```

This is the last `true` entry. E.g. for `z = 2`, this returns `4`. The next entry will be false because the player can only remove stones, such that the opponent will come out at a `true` entry.

Knowing this, our algorithm is almost complete. Start at a known `false` value (e.g. 0). Then, iteratively move to the next `false` value until you reach `n`.

```
bool isWinner(long long n)
{
    double loser = 0;
    while(n > loser)
        loser =  floor(0.5 * (1 + 2 * loser + sqrt(1 + 4 * loser))) + 1;
    return n != loser;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Games like this ([Towers of Hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) is another classic example) are meant to illustrate the mathematical principles of induction and recursion, with recursion being particularly relevant in programming.

We want to determine whether a pile of *n* stones is a winning pile or a losing pile. Intuitively, a winning pile is one so that no matter what sequence of choices your opponent makes you can always take some number of stones to guarantee you will win. Similarly, a losing pile is one such that no matter what choice you make, you always leave your opponent a winning strategy.

Obviously, *n = 0* is a losing pile; you've already lost. And *n = 1* is a winning pile since you take one stone and leave your opponent *n=0*. What about *n=2*? Well, you are only allowed to take one stone, at which point you have given your opponent a winning pile (*n=1*), so *n=2* is a losing number. We can make this mathematically more precise.

> **Definition:** An integer *n* is a *loser* if *n=0* or for every integer *k* between 1 and *sqrt(n)*, *n-k* is a *winner*. An integer *n* is a *winner* if there exists some integer *k* between 1 and *sqrt(n)* such that *n-k* is a *loser*.

In this definition, *n* is the size of the pile, *k* is the number of stones you choose to take. A pile is a losing pile if every valid number of stones to remove gives your opponent a winning pile and a winning pile is one where **some** choice gives your opponent a losing pile.

Of course, that definition should make you a little uneasy because we actually have no idea if it makes sense for anything other than *n=0,1,2*, which we already checked. Perhaps some number fits the definition of both a winner **and** a loser, or neither definition. This would certainly be confusing. This is where induction comes in.

> **Theorem:** Every nonnegative integer is either a winner or a loser, but not both.

**Proof:** We'll use the principle of [Strong or Complete Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction). We know that *n=0* is a loser (by definition) and we've already shown that *n=1* is a winner and *n=2* is a loser directly. Those are our base cases.

Now let's consider some integer *n_0 > 2* and we'll assume (using strong induction) that every nonnegative integer less than *n_0* is either a winner or a loser, but not both. Let *s = floor(sqrt(n_0))* and consider the set of integers *P = {n_0-s, n_0-s+1, ..., n_0 - 1}*. (Since *{1, 2, ..., s}* is the set of possible choices of stones to remove, *P* is the set of piles I can leave my opponent with.) By strong induction, since each value in *P* is a nonnegative integer less than *n_0*, each of them is either a winner or a loser (but not both). If **any** value in *P* is a loser, then by definition, *n_0* is a winner (because you remove enough stones to leave your opponent that losing pile). If not, then **every** value in *P* is a winner, so then *n_0* is a loser (because no matter how many stones you take, your opponent is still left with a winning pile). Therefore, *n_0* is either a winner or a loser, but not both.

By strong induction, we conclude that every nonnegative integer is either a winner or a loser but not both.

**QED**

OK, that was pretty straightforward if you are comfortable with induction. But all we've shown is that our very intuitive definition actually makes sense and that every pile you get is either a winner (if you play it right) or a loser (if your opponent plays it right). How do we determine which is which?

Well, induction leads right to recursion. Let's write recursive functions for our two definitions: is *n* a winner or a loser? Here's some C-like pseudocode without error checking.

```
bool is_winner(int n) {
  // check all valid numbers of stones to remove (k)
  for (int k = 1; k <= sqrt(n); k++) {
    if (is_loser(n-k)) {
      // I can force the loser n-k on my opponent, so n is a winner
      return true;
    }
  }
  // I didn't find a way to force a loser on my opponent, so this must be a loser.
  return false;
}

bool is_loser(int n) {
  if (n == 0) {  // this is our base case
    return true;
  }
  for (int k = 1; k <= sqrt(n); k++) {
    if (!is_winner(n-k)) {
      // we found a way to give them a pile that ISN'T a winner, so this isn't a loser
      return false;
    }
  }
  // Nope: every pile we can give our opponent is a winner, so this pile is a loser
  return true;
}
```

Of course, the code above is somewhat redundant since we've already shown that every number is either a winner or a loser. Therefore, it makes more sense to implement `is_loser` as just returning `!is_winner` or vice-versa. Perhaps we'll just do `is_winner` as a stand-alone implementation.

```
bool is_winner(int n) {
  if (n < 0) {
    // raise error
  } else if (n == 0) {
    return false; // 0 is a loser
  } else {
    for (int k = 1; k <= sqrt(n); k++) {
      if (!is_winner(n-k)) {
        // we can give opponent a loser, this is a winner
        return true;
      }
    }
    // all choices give our opponent a winner, this is a loser
    return false;
  }
}
```

To use this function to answer the question, if the game starts with *n* stones and player A goes first and both players play optimally, player A wins if `is_winner(n)` and player B wins if `!is_winner(n)`. To figure out what their plays should be, if you have a winning pile, you should choose some valid *k* such that *n-k* is a loser (it doesn't matter which one, but the largest value will make the game end fastest) and if you are given a losing pile, it doesn't matter what you choose -- that is the point of a loser, but again, choosing the largest value of *k* will make the game end sooner.

None of this really considers performance. Since *n* could be quite large, there are a number of things you could consider. Like, for example, pre-computing the common small values of *n* that you are going to consider, or using [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), at least within a single recursive call. Furthermore, as I suggested previously, removing the largest value of *k* ends the game with fewer turns. Similarly, if you reverse the loops and check the largest allowed values of *k* first, you should be able to reduce the number of recursive calls.

Of course, the really fast way to do this is to do some more math and figure out some simple properties of *n* you can check that will determine whether or not it is a winner or a loser.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Solution {
    public boolean canWinNim(int n) {
        if(n % 4 == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer will be much better if you explain why you're doing what you're doing.  In this case though, it appears you are giving the answer for traditional Nim, not the game as modified in the question.